# is it possible to write some code inside the route?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using vue router to create a logout functionality.Vue router normally expects a component to be passed, but in my case the logout button is not visible hence cannot be called from the UI anywhere,so to invoke it i have to manually write `/logout` in the url below is the code i wrote for that

**router.js**

```
{
    path: '/logout',
    name: 'Logout',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ '@/views/Logout.vue'),
    meta: {
      auth: 'public'
    }
  },
```

**Logout.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>Logout</h1>
</template>

<script>

export default{
    mounted(){
          this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout').then(() => {
    this.$router.push('/login')
  }).catch(() => {
    
  })
    }
}
</script>
```

while this does seem to work just fine i normally would see the template text on the browser for some time until the state data is removed then its taken back to login page, can we achieve the same behavior using just the router file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct way to do this. `<h1>Logout</h1>` is not needed because it can flicker if `dispatch('auth/logout')` takes some time.

Alternatively, the route can have no `component`, because it is never rendered, actions can happen in `beforeEnter` hook:

```
{
    path: '/logout',
    name: 'Logout',
    async beforeEnter(from, to, next) {
        await this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout');
        next('/login')
    }
}
```

},